# Create a Multiprocess script from a system consisting of multiple files

Tags: python-3.x, threadpool, python-multithreading

Hi guys im not too into python but need to do some research. The problem mainly consists of a file that calculates a large number of non linear equations which takes quite some time. The idea is to implement Multiprocessing in some way. I was wondering if there is a "correct" way to do this, since the main file calls the "computational" script, should i focus on the main or the computational file for multiprocessing? There are more files involved but this should be a start.

Main file:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from properties_basic import *
import sys

sys.path.append('../physics_sup/')

import os, glob, shutil
for filename in glob.glob("obl_point_data_*"):
    os.remove(filename)
for filename in glob.glob("restart.pkl"):
    os.remove(filename)
for filename in glob.glob("data.pvd"):
    os.remove(filename)

for filename in glob.glob("__pycache__/conversio*"):
    os.remove(filename)
for filename in glob.glob("__pycache__/mode*"):
    os.remove(filename)
for filename in glob.glob("__pycache__/operato*"):
    os.remove(filename)
for filename in glob.glob("__pycache__/physi*"):
    os.remove(filename)
for filename in glob.glob("__pycache__/prope*"):
    os.remove(filename)


from model_benchmark import Model
from darts.engines import value_vector, redirect_darts_output
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

grid_1D = False
redirect_darts_output('run.log')
n = Model()
n.init()

injectionsrate = np.genfromtxt('injectionrate.txt')[0:].astype(float) #np.genfromtxt('InjectionMonthly.txt')[0:].astype(float)#
injectionsrate = injectionsrate / 20

#mu_w = CP.PropsSI('V', 'T', 22, 'P|liquid', bar2pa(130), 'Water') * 1000
#n.property_container.viscosity_ev = dict([('wat', ViscosityConst(mu_w))])


NT = 16 # 16
runtime = 50 # 365
#increase = np.repeat(0.000005,37)
#print(increase)

for i in range(NT):
    n.inj_rate = injectionsrate[i]
    n.injection_temperature = 273.15 + 22
    n.set_boundary_conditions(injectionrate=injectionsrate[i], tempinj=273.15+22)
    #n.property_container.kinetic_rate_ev = kinetic_advanced(comp_min=1e-11, rsa=int(2e-05 + increase[NT]))
    n.run_python(runtime)
    time_data = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(n.physics.engine.time_data)
    time_data.to_pickle("darts_time_data.pkl")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('time_data.xlsx')
    time_data.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
    n.export_vtk()

n.save_restart_data()

n.load_restart_data()

injectionsrate2 = np.genfromtxt('injectionrate.txt')[15:].astype(float) #np.genfromtxt('InjectionMonthly.txt')[191:].astype(float)#
injectionsrate2 = injectionsrate2 / 20 #*2

#mu_w2 = CP.PropsSI('V', 'T', 10, 'P|liquid', bar2pa(130), 'Water') * 1000
#n.property_container.viscosity_ev = dict([('wat', ViscosityConst(1.3))])
n.property_container.kinetic_rate_ev = kinetic_advanced(comp_min=1e-11, rsa=2e-03)
days = 200
NT2 = 21 #21 # 252
runtime2 =   50 # 30

for i in range(NT2):
    n.inj_rate = injectionsrate2[i]
    n.injection_temperature = 273.15 + 10
    n.set_boundary_conditions(injectionrate=injectionsrate2[i], tempinj=273.15 + 10)
    n.run_python(runtime2)
    time_data2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(n.physics.engine.time_data)
    time_data2.to_pickle("darts_time_data2.pkl")
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter('time_data2.xlsx')
    time_data2.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet1')
    writer.save()
    writer.close()
    n.export_vtk()


n.print_timers()
n.print_stat()

import darts.tools.plot_darts
from darts.tools.plot_darts import *

p_w = 'I1'
#ax = plot_water_rate_darts(p_w, time_data)
time_dataInjection = pd.read_pickle("darts_time_data.pkl")
time_dataInjection2= pd.read_pickle("darts_time_data2.pkl")
#ax = darts.tools.plot_darts.plot_water_rate_darts(p_w, time_dataInjection)
ax2 = darts.tools.plot_darts.plot_water_rate_darts(p_w, time_dataInjection2)

p_w2 = 'P1'
#ax3 = darts.tools.plot_darts.plot_water_rate_darts(p_w2, time_dataInjection)
ax4 = darts.tools.plot_darts.plot_water_rate_darts(p_w2, time_dataInjection2)
ax5 = darts.tools.plot_darts.plot_bhp_darts(p_w, time_dataInjection2)
plt.show()
```

The Non linear calculator:

```
from math import fabs
import pickle
import os
import numpy as np

from darts.engines import *
from darts.engines import print_build_info as engines_pbi
from darts.physics import print_build_info as physics_pbi
from darts.print_build_info import print_build_info as package_pbi


class DartsModel:

    def __init__(self):
 
        # print out build information
        engines_pbi()
        physics_pbi()
        package_pbi()
        self.timer = timer_node()  # Create time_node object for time record
        self.timer.start()  # Start time record
        self.timer.node["simulation"] = timer_node()  # Create timer.node called "simulation" to record simulation time
        self.timer.node["newton update"] = timer_node()
        self.timer.node[
            "initialization"] = timer_node()  # Create timer.node called "initialization" to record initialization time
        self.timer.node["initialization"].start()  # Start recording "initialization" time

        self.params = sim_params()  # Create sim_params object to set simulation parameters

        self.timer.node["initialization"].stop()  # Stop recording "initialization" time


    def init(self):
        self.reservoir.init_wells()
        self.physics.init_wells(self.reservoir.wells)
        self.set_initial_conditions()
        self.set_boundary_conditions()
        self.set_op_list()
        self.reset()

    def reset(self)
        self.physics.engine.init(self.reservoir.mesh, ms_well_vector(self.reservoir.wells),
                                 op_vector(self.op_list),
                                 self.params, self.timer.node["simulation"])

    def set_initial_conditions(self):
        pass

    def set_boundary_conditions(self):
        pass

    def set_op_list(self):
        self.op_list = [self.physics.acc_flux_itor]

    def run(self, days=0):
        if days:
            runtime = days
        else:
            runtime = self.runtime
        self.physics.engine.run(runtime)

    def run_python(self, days=0, restart_dt=0, log_3d_body_path=0, timestep_python=False):
        if days:
            runtime = days
        else:
            runtime = self.runtime

        mult_dt = self.params.mult_ts
        max_dt = self.params.max_ts
        self.e = self.physics.engine
        t = self.e.t
        if fabs(t) < 1e-15:
            dt = self.params.first_ts
        elif restart_dt > 0:
            dt = restart_dt
        else:
            dt = self.params.max_ts

        runtime += t
        ts = 0
        
        if log_3d_body_path and self.physics.n_vars == 3:
            self.body_path_start()

        while t < runtime:
            if timestep_python:
                 converged = self.e.run_timestep(dt, t)
            else:
                 converged = self.run_timestep_python(dt, t)
            if converged:
                t += dt
                ts = ts + 1
                print("# %d \tT = %3g\tDT = %2g\tNI = %d\tLI=%d"
                      % (ts, t, dt, self.e.n_newton_last_dt, self.e.n_linear_last_dt))

                dt *= mult_dt
                if dt > max_dt:
                    dt = max_dt

                if t + dt > runtime:
                    dt = runtime - t

                if log_3d_body_path and self.physics.n_vars == 3:
                    self.body_path_add_bodys(t)
                    nb_begin = self.reservoir.nx * self.reservoir.ny * (self.body_path_map_layer - 1) * 3
                    nb_end = self.reservoir.nx * self.reservoir.ny * (self.body_path_map_layer) * 3

                    self.save_matlab_map(self.body_path_axes[0] + '_ts_' + str(ts), self.e.X[nb_begin:nb_end:3])
                    self.save_matlab_map(self.body_path_axes[1] + '_ts_' + str(ts), self.e.X[nb_begin + 1:nb_end:3])
                    self.save_matlab_map(self.body_path_axes[2] + '_ts_' + str(ts), self.e.X[nb_begin + 2:nb_end:3])
            else:
                dt /= mult_dt
                print("Cut timestep to %2.3f" % dt)
                if dt < 1e-8:
                    break
        self.e.t = runtime

        print("TS = %d(%d), NI = %d(%d), LI = %d(%d)" % (self.e.stat.n_timesteps_total, self.e.stat.n_timesteps_wasted,
                                                         self.e.stat.n_newton_total, self.e.stat.n_newton_wasted,
                                                         self.e.stat.n_linear_total, self.e.stat.n_linear_wasted))

    def load_restart_data(self, filename='restart.pkl'):

        if os.path.exists(filename):
            with open(filename, "rb") as fp:
                data = pickle.load(fp)
                days, X, arr_n = data
                self.physics.engine.t = days
                self.physics.engine.X = value_vector(X)
                self.physics.engine.Xn = value_vector(X)
                self.physics.engine.op_vals_arr_n = value_vector(arr_n)

    def save_restart_data(self, filename='restart.pkl'):
        """
        Function to save the simulation data for restart usage.
        :param filename: Name of the file where restart_data stores.
        """
        t = np.copy(self.physics.engine.t)
        X = np.copy(self.physics.engine.X)
        arr_n = np.copy(self.physics.engine.op_vals_arr_n)
        data = [t, X, arr_n]
        with open(filename, "wb") as fp:
            pickle.dump(data, fp, 4)

    def check_performance(self, overwrite=0, diff_norm_normalized_tol=1e-10, diff_abs_max_normalized_tol=1e-7,
                          rel_diff_tol=1, perf_file=''):

        fail = 0
        data_et = self.load_performance_data(perf_file)
        if data_et and not overwrite:
            data = self.get_performance_data()
            nb = self.reservoir.mesh.n_res_blocks
            nv = self.physics.n_vars

            for v in range(nv):
                sol_et = data_et['solution'][v:nb * nv:nv]
                diff = data['solution'][v:nb * nv:nv] - sol_et
                sol_range = np.max(sol_et) - np.min(sol_et)
                diff_abs = np.abs(diff)
                diff_norm = np.linalg.norm(diff)
                diff_norm_normalized = diff_norm / len(sol_et) / sol_range
                diff_abs_max_normalized = np.max(diff_abs) / sol_range
                if diff_norm_normalized > diff_norm_normalized_tol or diff_abs_max_normalized > diff_abs_max_normalized_tol:
                    fail += 1
                    print(
                        '#%d solution check failed for variable %s (range %f): L2(diff)/len(diff)/range = %.2E (tol %.2E), max(abs(diff))/range %.2E (tol %.2E), max(abs(diff)) = %.2E' \
                        % (fail, self.physics.vars[v], sol_range, diff_norm_normalized, diff_norm_normalized_tol,
                           diff_abs_max_normalized, diff_abs_max_normalized_tol, np.max(diff_abs)))
            for key, value in sorted(data.items()):
                if key == 'solution' or type(value) != int:
                    continue
                reference = data_et[key]

                if reference == 0:
                    if value != 0:
                        print('#%d parameter %s is %d (was 0)' % (fail, key, value))
                        fail += 1
                else:
                    rel_diff = (value - data_et[key]) / reference * 100
                    if abs(rel_diff) > rel_diff_tol:
                        print('#%d parameter %s is %d (was %d, %+.2f%%)' % (fail, key, value, reference, rel_diff))
                        fail += 1
            if not fail:
                print('OK, \t%.2f s' % self.timer.node['simulation'].get_timer())
                return 0
            else:
                print('FAIL, \t%.2f s' % self.timer.node['simulation'].get_timer())
                return 1
        else:
            self.save_performance_data(perf_file)
            print('SAVED')
            return 0

    def get_performance_data(self):

        perf_data = dict()
        perf_data['solution'] = np.copy(self.physics.engine.X)
        perf_data['reservoir blocks'] = self.reservoir.mesh.n_res_blocks
        perf_data['variables'] = self.physics.n_vars
        perf_data['OBL resolution'] = self.physics.n_points
        perf_data['operators'] = self.physics.n_ops
        perf_data['timesteps'] = self.physics.engine.stat.n_timesteps_total
        perf_data['wasted timesteps'] = self.physics.engine.stat.n_timesteps_wasted
        perf_data['newton iterations'] = self.physics.engine.stat.n_newton_total
        perf_data['wasted newton iterations'] = self.physics.engine.stat.n_newton_wasted
        perf_data['linear iterations'] = self.physics.engine.stat.n_linear_total
        perf_data['wasted linear iterations'] = self.physics.engine.stat.n_linear_wasted

        sim = self.timer.node['simulation']
        jac = sim.node['jacobian assembly']
        perf_data['simulation time'] = sim.get_timer()
        perf_data['linearization time'] = jac.get_timer()
        perf_data['linear solver time'] = sim.node['linear solver solve'].get_timer() + sim.node[
            'linear solver setup'].get_timer()
        interp = jac.node['interpolation']
        perf_data['interpolation incl. generation time'] = interp.get_timer()

        return perf_data

    def save_performance_data(self, file_name=''):
        import platform

        if file_name == '':
            file_name = 'perf_' + platform.system().lower()[:3] + '.pkl'
        data = self.get_performance_data()
        with open(file_name, "wb") as fp:
            pickle.dump(data, fp, 4)

    @staticmethod
    def load_performance_data(file_name=''):
        import platform
        if file_name == '':
            file_name = 'perf_' + platform.system().lower()[:3] + '.pkl'
        if os.path.exists(file_name):
            with open(file_name, "rb") as fp:
                return pickle.load(fp)
        return 0

    def print_timers(self):

        print(self.timer.print("", ""))

    def print_stat(self):

        self.physics.engine.print_stat()

    def plot_layer_map(self, map_data, k, name, transpose=0):

        import plotly
        import plotly.graph_objs as go

        nxny = self.reservoir.nx * self.reservoir.ny
        layer_indexes = np.arange(nxny * (k - 1), nxny * k)
        layer_data = np.zeros(nxny)
        # for correct vizualization of inactive cells
        layer_data.fill(np.nan)

        active_mask = np.where(self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[layer_indexes] > -1)
        layer_data[active_mask] = map_data[self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[layer_indexes][active_mask]]

        layer_data = layer_data.reshape(self.reservoir.ny, self.reservoir.nx)
        if transpose:
            layer_data = layer_data.transpose()
            y_axis = dict(scaleratio=1, scaleanchor='x', title='X, block')
            x_axis = dict(title='Y, block')
        else:
            x_axis = dict(scaleratio=1, scaleanchor='x', title='X, block')
            y_axis = dict(title='Y, block')

        data = [go.Heatmap(
            z=layer_data)]
        layout = go.Layout(title='%s, layer %d' % (name, k),
                           xaxis=x_axis,
                           yaxis=y_axis)
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='%s_%d_map.html' % (name, k))

    def plot_layer_map_offline(self, map_data, k, name, transpose=0):
        import plotly

        plotly.offline.init_notebook_mode()

        self.plot_layer_map(map_data, k, name, transpose)

    def plot_layer_surface(self, map_data, k, name, transpose=0):

        import plotly
        import plotly.graph_objs as go

        nxny = self.reservoir.nx * self.reservoir.ny
        layer_indexes = np.arange(nxny * (k - 1), nxny * k)
        layer_data = np.zeros(nxny)
        # for correct vizualization of inactive cells
        layer_data.fill(np.nan)

        active_mask = np.where(self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[layer_indexes] > -1)
        layer_data[active_mask] = map_data[self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[layer_indexes][active_mask]]

        layer_data = layer_data.reshape(self.reservoir.ny, self.reservoir.nx)
        if transpose:
            layer_data = layer_data.transpose()

        data = [go.Surface(z=layer_data)]
        plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='%s_%d_surf.html' % (name, k))

    def plot_geothermal_temp_layer_map(self, X, k, name, transpose=0):
        import plotly
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np
        from darts.models.physics.iapws.iapws_property import iapws_temperature_evaluator
        nxny = self.reservoir.nx * self.reservoir.ny

        temperature = iapws_temperature_evaluator()
        layer_pres_data = np.zeros(nxny)
        layer_enth_data = np.zeros(nxny)
        layer_indexes = np.arange(nxny * (k - 1), nxny * k)
        active_mask = np.where(self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[layer_indexes] > -1)
        layer_pres_data[active_mask] = X[2 * self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[layer_indexes][active_mask]]
        layer_enth_data[active_mask] = X[2 * self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[layer_indexes][active_mask] + 1]

        # used_data = map_data[2 * nxny * (k-1): 2 * nxny * k]
        T = np.zeros(nxny)
        T.fill(np.nan)
        for i in range(0, nxny):
            if self.reservoir.discretizer.global_to_local[nxny * (k - 1) + i] > -1:
                T[i] = temperature.evaluate([layer_pres_data[i], layer_enth_data[i]])

        layer_data = T.reshape(self.reservoir.ny, self.reservoir.nx)
        if transpose:
            layer_data = layer_data.transpose()
            y_axis = dict(scaleratio=1, scaleanchor='x', title='X, block')
            x_axis = dict(title='Y, block')
        else:
            x_axis = dict(scaleratio=1, scaleanchor='x', title='X, block')
            y_axis = dict(title='Y, block')

        data = [go.Heatmap(
            z=layer_data)]
        layout = go.Layout(title='%s, layer %d' % (name, k),
                           xaxis=x_axis,
                           yaxis=y_axis)
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        plotly.offline.plot(fig, filename='%s_%d_map.html' % (name, k))

    def plot_1d(self, map_data, name):
        import plotly
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np

        nx = self.reservoir.nx
        data = [go.Scatter(x=np.linspace(0, 1, nx), y=map_data[1:nx])]
        plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='%s_surf.html' % name)

    def plot_1d_all(self, map_data):
        import plotly
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np

        nx = self.reservoir.nx
        nc = self.physics.n_components

        data = []
        for i in range(nc - 1):
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=np.linspace(0, 1, nx), y=map_data[i + 1::nc][1:nx], dash='dash'))

        plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='Compositions.html')

    def plot_cumulative_totals_mass(self):

        import plotly.offline as po
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        nc = self.physics.n_components

        darts_df = pd.DataFrame(self.physics.engine.time_data)
        total_df = pd.DataFrame()
        total_df['time'] = darts_df['time']
        time_diff = darts_df['time'].diff()
        time_diff[0] = darts_df['time'][0]
        for c in range(nc):
            total_df['Total injection c %d' % c] = 0
            total_df['Total production c %d' % c] = 0
            search_str = ' : c %d rate (Kmol/day)' % c
            for col in darts_df.columns:
                if search_str in col:
                    inj_mass = darts_df[col] * time_diff
                    prod_mass = darts_df[col] * time_diff
                    # assuming that any well can inject and produce over the whole time
                    inj_mass[inj_mass < 0] = 0
                    prod_mass[prod_mass > 0] = 0
                    total_df['Total injection c %d' % c] += inj_mass
                    total_df['Total production c %d' % c] -= prod_mass

        data = []
        for c in range(nc):
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=total_df['time'], y=total_df['Total injection c %d' % c].cumsum(),
                                   name='%s injection' % self.physics.components[c]))
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=total_df['time'], y=total_df['Total production c %d' % c].cumsum(),
                                   name='%s production' % self.physics.components[c]))

        layout = go.Layout(title='Cumulative total masses (kmol)', xaxis=dict(title='Time (days)'),
                           yaxis=dict(title='Mass (kmols)'))
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        po.plot(fig, filename='Cumulative_totals_mass.html')

    def plot_mass_balance_error(self):

        import plotly.offline as po
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        nc = self.physics.n_components

        darts_df = pd.DataFrame(self.physics.engine.time_data)
        total_df = pd.DataFrame()
        total_df['time'] = darts_df['time']
        time_diff = darts_df['time'].diff()
        time_diff[0] = darts_df['time'][0]
        for c in range(nc):
            total_df['Total source-sink c %d' % c] = 0
            search_str = ' : c %d rate (Kmol/day)' % c
            for col in darts_df.columns:
                if search_str in col:
                    mass = darts_df[col] * time_diff
                    total_df['Total source-sink c %d' % c] += mass

        data = []
        for c in range(nc):
            total_df['Total mass balance error c %d' % c] = darts_df['FIPS c %d (kmol)' % c] - total_df[
                'Total source-sink c %d' % c].cumsum()
            total_df['Total mass balance error c %d' % c] -= darts_df['FIPS c %d (kmol)' % c][0] - \
                                                             total_df['Total source-sink c %d' % c][0]
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=total_df['time'], y=total_df['Total mass balance error c %d' % c],
                                   name='%s' % self.physics.components[c]))

        layout = go.Layout(title='Mass balance error (kmol)', xaxis=dict(title='Time (days)'),
                           yaxis=dict(title='Mass (kmols)'))
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        po.plot(fig, filename='Mass_balance_error.html')

    def plot_FIPS(self):
        import plotly.offline as po
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        nc = self.physics.n_components

        darts_df = pd.DataFrame(self.physics.engine.time_data)
        data = []
        for c in range(nc):
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=darts_df['time'], y=darts_df['FIPS c %d (kmol)' % c],
                                   name='%s' % self.physics.components[c]))

        layout = go.Layout(title='FIPS (kmol)', xaxis=dict(title='Time (days)'),
                           yaxis=dict(title='Mass (kmols)'))
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        po.plot(fig, filename='FIPS.html')

    def plot_totals_mass(self):
        import plotly.offline as po
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np
        import pandas as pd

        nc = self.physics.n_components

        darts_df = pd.DataFrame(self.physics.engine.time_data)
        total_df = pd.DataFrame()
        total_df['time'] = darts_df['time']
        for c in range(nc):
            total_df['Total injection c %d' % c] = 0
            total_df['Total production c %d' % c] = 0
            search_str = ' : c %d rate (Kmol/day)' % c
            for col in darts_df.columns:
                if search_str in col:
                    inj_mass = darts_df[col].copy()
                    prod_mass = darts_df[col].copy()
                    # assuming that any well can inject and produce over the whole time
                    inj_mass[inj_mass < 0] = 0
                    prod_mass[prod_mass > 0] = 0
                    total_df['Total injection c %d' % c] += inj_mass
                    total_df['Total production c %d' % c] -= prod_mass

        data = []
        for c in range(nc):
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=total_df['time'], y=total_df['Total injection c %d' % c],
                                   name='%s injection' % self.physics.components[c]))
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=total_df['time'], y=total_df['Total production c %d' % c],
                                   name='%s production' % self.physics.components[c]))

        layout = go.Layout(title='Total mass rates (kmols/day)', xaxis=dict(title='Time (days)'),
                           yaxis=dict(title='Rate (kmols/day)'))
        fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)
        po.plot(fig, filename='Totals_mass_rates.html')

    def plot_1d_compare(self, map_data1, map_data2):

        import plotly
        import plotly.graph_objs as go
        import numpy as np

        nx = self.reservoir.nx
        nc = self.physics.n_components

        data = []
        for i in range(nc - 1):
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=np.linspace(0, 1, nx), y=map_data1[i + 1::nc][1:nx],
                                   name="Comp = %d, dt = 5 days" % (i + 1)))

        for i in range(nc - 1):
            data.append(go.Scatter(x=np.linspace(0, 1, nx), y=map_data2[i + 1::nc][1:nx],
                                   name="Comp = %d, dt = 50 days" % (i + 1), line=dict(dash='dot')))

        plotly.offline.plot(data, filename='Compositions.html')

    def body_path_start(self):
        with open('body_path.txt', "w") as fp:
            itor = self.physics.acc_flux_itor
            self.processed_body_idxs = set()
            for i, p in enumerate(itor.axis_points):
                fp.write('%d %lf %lf %s\n' % (p, itor.axis_min[i], itor.axis_max[i], self.body_path_axes[i]))
            fp.write('Body Index Data\n')

    def body_path_add_bodys(self, time):
        with open('body_path.txt', "a") as fp:
            fp.write('T=%lf\n' % time)
            itor = self.physics.acc_flux_itor
            all_idxs = set(itor.body_data.keys())
            new_idxs = all_idxs - self.processed_body_idxs
            for i in new_idxs:
                fp.write('%d\n' % i)
            self.processed_body_idxs = all_idxs

    def save_matlab_map(self, name, np_arr):
        import scipy.io
        scipy.io.savemat(name + '.mat', dict(x=np_arr))

    def export_vtk(self, file_name='data', local_cell_data={}, global_cell_data={}, vars_data_dtype=np.float32,
                   export_grid_data=True):

        # get current engine time
        t = self.physics.engine.t
        nb = self.reservoir.mesh.n_res_blocks
        nv = self.physics.n_vars
        X = np.array(self.physics.engine.X, copy=False)

        for v in range(nv):
            local_cell_data[self.physics.vars[v]] = X[v:nb * nv:nv].astype(vars_data_dtype)

        self.reservoir.export_vtk(file_name, t, local_cell_data, global_cell_data, export_grid_data)

    # destructor to force to destroy all created C objects and free memory
    def __del__(self):
        for name in list(vars(self).keys()):
            delattr(self, name)


    def run_timestep_python(self, dt, t):
        max_newt = self.params.max_i_newton
        max_residual = np.zeros(max_newt + 1)
        self.e.n_linear_last_dt = 0
        well_tolerance_coefficient = 1e2
        self.timer.node['simulation'].start()
        for i in range(max_newt+1):
            self.e.run_single_newton_iteration(dt)
            self.e.newton_residual_last_dt = self.e.calc_newton_residual()

            max_residual[i] = self.e.newton_residual_last_dt
            counter = 0
            for j in range(i):
                if abs(max_residual[i] - max_residual[j])/max_residual[i] < 1e-3:
                    counter += 1
            if counter > 2:
                print("Stationary point detected!")
                break

            self.e.well_residual_last_dt = self.e.calc_well_residual()
            self.e.n_newton_last_dt = i
            #  check tolerance if it converges
            if ((self.e.newton_residual_last_dt < self.params.tolerance_newton and self.e.well_residual_last_dt < well_tolerance_coefficient * self.params.tolerance_newton )
                    or self.e.n_newton_last_dt == self.params.max_i_newton):
                if (i > 0):  # min_i_newton
                    break
            r_code = self.e.solve_linear_equation()
            self.timer.node["newton update"].start()
            self.e.apply_newton_update(dt)
            self.timer.node["newton update"].stop()
        # End of newton loop
        converged = self.e.post_newtonloop(dt, t)
        self.timer.node['simulation'].stop()
        return converged
```

Comment: there are lots of file operations. This would suggest `threading` or `asyncio` (asynchronous input / output) in preference to multiprocessing.

Comment: You need to identify which part of the code is slowing the process down. use the `time` module for this...